# How to use symbol of \lambda from documentclass{acmart} in documentclass{article}?

Tags: symbols, document-classes, greek

Basically I want to use the symbol of `\lambda` in `\documentclass{acmart}` in a different document class without changing any other symbols.

(I'm the guy from a [previous question who asked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/681821/273733) about using `\lambda` from the txfonts package, apparently it was a very similar lambda but not the one I was looking for, thanks)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea is the same as in the previous answers, but there are further complications, I'm afraid, because `acmart` uses `newtxmath` with the `libertine` option. The first step suggested in the other answer gives the same result, whereas the second one shows

```
> \OML/nxlmi/m/it/9 .
```

But here it's not sufficient to replace `txmi` with `nxlmi`, because the font definition file takes different paths according to the options `newtxmath` is loaded with.

In this case it's simpler to add the font definitions manually.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareFontFamily{OML}{nxlmi}{\skewchar\font =127 }
\DeclareFontShape{OML}{nxlmi}{m}{it}{
  <-6.3> nxlmi035
  <6.3-8.6> nxlmi037
  <8.6-> nxlmi03
}{}


\DeclareRobustCommand{\varlambda}{\text{\usefont{OML}{nxlmi}{m}{it}\symbol{"15}}}

\begin{document}

$\alpha\beta\lambda\varlambda$

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is what you get with `\documentclass{acmart}` and just `$\lambda$` in the document body.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer both questions, much love.